# OpenID Connect - Refreshing ID token

Tags: token, openid-connect, refresh-token

I have been implementing OpenID Connect for a native app (which has server component). I'm mimicking the authorization code flow for native apps. And after OIDC flow, the ID token, Accesstoken and refresh token are received on the server side. And the server validates ID Token and returns app session to the native client.

I'm not clear on the use case for refresh token in this flow. Does it make sense to support refreshing ID token in this scenario? i.e. if app session expires, and client passes expired app session to the server, then server can take the refresh token using refresh token and get new ID token from OAuth server and mint new app session. This approach seems to be as good as (not exactly same) having long lived app session, b'coz app can always renew the app session in lieu of its expired session.

I tried Okta developer console and it is supporting refreshing ID token. But i'm not clear on the usecase for refreshing ID token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OAuth, the ID token represents proof of the authentication event. Meanwhile, the first refresh token issued after user authentication represents the lifetime of the client's session with APIs.

When token refresh occurs, a new refresh token is usually also issued. It does not make sense to issue a new ID token, as described in the relevant section of the [OpenID Connect Specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#RefreshTokenResponse). An authorization server can optionally return an ID token in the refresh response. In my experience, the only real use case for doing so is to enable use of OAuth libraries that expect all 3 tokens to be present in a token response.

Web clients often use a backend that bootstraps a cookie based session after validating the ID token. The cookies are encrypted and contain or reference the underlying OAuth tokens. Cookies may be rewritten after a token refresh, but the client cannot extend its own session with APIs just because it gets a new ID token. Instead, the API session expires when the lifetime of the original refresh token expires.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. "_Cookies may be rewritten after a token refresh._" Did you mean that the server should return new cookie in the response after the tokens are refreshed? Isn't this same as having long lived cookie? Is "refresh token" solving anything here? "_the API session expires when the lifetime of the original refresh token expires._" Sorry, what do you mean by session? The cookie?

Comment: An HTTP message credential (an access token or cookie) is used when calling APIs. This should have a short lifetime, eg 15 minutes, so that if the credential is stolen somehow, it cannot be abused for long. The refresh token enables this. By session I mean the time for which APIs (resource servers) can be called.

Comment: Thanks again Gary. "_if the credential is stolen somehow, it cannot be abused for long. The refresh token enables this_". My understanding of refreshing the token is that, if client passes expired token, then server would automatically refresh the token and return new token to the client. So in that case stolen token can also be used to get new token right? Only if we know that the token is stolen, then it can somehow be blacklisted.

Comment: Ideally the client should use a short lived API credential, eg 15 minutes, which is how OAuth is designed. APIs must reject requests with expired access tokens.